# Track "Thanks Page" of PloneFormGen form

Tags: google-analytics, plone, ploneformgen, goal-tracking

I would like to allow Google Analytics to track that the user has made it to the Thanks Page of my PloneFormGen (version 1.7.1) form on a Plone 4.1.6 site. But that page is displayed using the same URL as the form itself.

I tried to use the *Custom Success Action* override and set it to `redirect_to:string:thank-you` (where `thank-you` is the ID of the page). But that (surprise, surprise) redirects the browser to the Thanks Page. And while this does lead to a separate URL, the POST data is lost and thus the user gets the message "No input was received. Please visit the form." Not exactly what I planned.

What should I do to show the Thanks Page on a separate URL?

Comment: Which PFG version are you using? 1.6.0 is recommended with Plone-4.1.x and the custom success action works fine there for me, no lost data.

Comment: @IdaEbkes: I'm using PloneFormGen version 1.7.1. I've included that information in the question now. Thanks.

Comment: @IdaEbkes As I read the documentation, version 1.7 *is* the right version for Plone 4.1 and up:"PFG 1.7 is intended for use with Plone 4.1+. If you're using Plone < 4.1, PFG 1.6 will be a better choice."

Comment: Ok, I had an error using PFG-1.7.6 with Plone-4.1.6, but no time to investigate further. Just saying, that PFG works as expected and the way you want it. Yet, Steve's proposed add-on looks quite interesting, curious about your experience with it...

Comment: Not sure I understand... The URL for the form is example.com/test-form. The URL for the thanks page is also example.com/test-form. The JS for Analytics includes `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])` (no URL specified). So how is Analytics going to know that the conversion took place? (Disclaimer: I'm no Analytics expert...)
The only way to get a separate URL for the thanks page is to use the `redirect_to` expression, which results in the thanks page not receiving POST data.
So unless I'm missing something, it seems that it is *not* doing things the way I want it. :)

Comment: Sorry misunderstanding, I thought, that the save-adapter doesn't receive the data, not the landing page.

Comment: No problem. I was just curious if I was doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Yoder, [collective.googleanalytics](http://plone.org/products/collective.googleanalytics) has some hooks to instrument PloneFormGen thanks pages. It will also do some other great magic like tracking validation errors.

Comment: Using collective.googleanalytics would indeed have been a great solution! (That's why I'm going to accept this answer.)

However, since we are using collective.lineage, we cannot set one profile for the whole Plone site; we need to have separate profiles per subfolder. (I had not included this in my question since it did not seem relevant, sorry.)

I'll probably go with a custom (one-off) solution where I'll override the `plone.analytics` viewlet for the `IPloneFormGenThanksPage` interface to add the URL of the thanks page to the `_trackPageview` variable in the JavaScript.

Comment: If you already know what URL you want to track, take a look at collective.analyticspanel

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't quite suitable for my use case (since I do not know beforehand which objects the customer will create). But it definitely looks like an interesting package.